# How to update an input ngModel by updating its value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an input which is being updated through a directive. I save one value on one of the attributes but I want to get the text as well in the input, so the input has another ng-model.

However, when the input is updated, it doesn't update the model. I've tried firing a change event as well but doesn't seem to work either. The model doesn't get updated.

I've simplified an example with a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vmh775AFp4d0Epg8taaO?p=preview).

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
var input;
$(document).ready(function(){
  input = $('input');
});


app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  setTimeout(function(){
    $scope.$apply(function(){
      input.val('test');  

    });

  },1000);

  $scope.$watch('data.text', function(newValue,oldValue){

    if (newValue === 'test'){
      alert('Eureka!');
    }
  });
});
```

As you'll see, Eureka is never triggered. Just to clarify, in the plunker I could just access the $scope and change it, but I have a code similar to this in a directive where I don't have access to that scope. I just want things to work as if I write something manually. You can get the Eureka by removing a `t` and adding it back.

Comment: its working fine , remove test and add again you can see the alert

Comment: No it's not. It should show an alert with Eureka in one second (when the text appears on the input)

Comment: why are you setting the text value and not the data.text variable? $scope.data = {};
  
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.data.text = 'test';
  },1000);

Comment: i removed 't' in 'test' and added 't' again and i am getting alert

Comment: Prash, it should work without doing that, that's my question.

Comment: @doodeec because I don't have access to the $scope, as I said I've simplified things there just to illustrate the issue.

Comment: where is your directive code ??

Comment: How did you fire the change event? Here's the plunk with .trigger that works: http://plnkr.co/edit/MwcyWCaSnqMElMyEXGrk?p=preview

Comment: @AntonioLaguna okay, but that's a completely wrong approach from my point of view... you should manipulate the model directly (for example via shared service between directive and model, or by two-way binding), not by changing the input field value

Comment: @doodec consider situation where you have to work with external library, let's say jQuery's datepicker. It changes the value attribute, not the model, so there are situations where you have to write custom directives to handle this kind of behaviour. Of course, manipulating DOM attributes in controller is not the best approach, but this is a simplified example as OP stated.

Comment: You seem to be right @package though for some reason it's not working on my code... Can you add yours and I'll accept since that solves that issue?

Comment: @package it doesn't work because I have an old version of AngularJS

Comment: @AntonioLaguna do you use jQuery in your project?

Comment: Yes I do @package. If you update your plunker to use angular 1.1.5 it fails.

Comment: @AntonioLaguna then it should work. Try different events, e.g. keypress, keyup instead of change. Do you get any errors in the console? And what version of Angular are you using exactly?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i modify the scope from the console (outside of angular)
Hope its to any help

```
$("input").scope().$apply(function(scope){
    scope.data = "new value";
})
```